# Angular ngOptions with orderBy based on object

Tags: angularjs, object, html-select

I'm trying to generate a  statement based on an object that stores a multi-level structure like:

```
{ "reptype0": {"index":0, "value":{...}},"reptype1": {"index":1, "value":{...}},....}
```

to be used in a  tag with an angular ngOptions like:

```
<select id="repType" 
        name="repType"  
        ng-model="representationType.rtmodel"
        ng-options="reptype for (reptype,repsubtypes) in representationTypes">
    <option value=''>--select a value--</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to order the options by the value of the "index" attribute but I cannot make 'orderBy' work as it is looking for an array.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already found, `orderBy` looks for an array rather than an object. Whenever I've run in to this issue, I've always converted the object in to an array and used that.

**Controller**

```
$scope.getRepresentationTypesArray = getRepresentationTypesArray;

function getRepresentationTypesArray () {
  var representationTypes = {};

  angular.forEach($scope.representationTypes, function (type, subTypes) {
    representationTypes[type] = [];

    angular.forEach(subTypes, function (subType) {
      representationTypes[type][subType.index] = subType.value;
    });
  });

  return representationTypes;
}
```

**View**

```
<select id="repType" 
        name="repType"  
        ng-model="representationType.rtmodel"
        ng-options="reptype for (reptype,repsubtypes) in getRepresentationTypesArray()">
  <option value=''>--select a value--</option>
</select>
```

The `getRepresentationTypesArray()` method would return your data in form:

```
{ "reptype0": [ {...} ], "reptype1": [ {...} ], ....}
```

With the data already sorted by index for you to use directly in your `ng-options`.